# Hot Code Replace with Vaadin + SBT + Scala + Eclipse setup

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, vaadin, projects-and-solutions

How can I properly set up a project using

- Vaadin
- SBT
- Scala
- Eclipse

so I can benefit from Hot Code Replace and debugging during development in Eclipse?

I've already configured my SBT project with all dependencies, sbteclipse, sbt-vaadin-plugin and xsbt-web-plugin.

I can use Jetty out of SBT, but I also want to use Hot Code Replace and the debugger in Eclipse.

Do I need to run it using Eclipse? Do I need to configure a Dynamic Web Project?

Maybe I'm missing some key point. Just pointing me into the direction how my setup should look like in the end would be very nice.

Comment: I am not familar with SBT, how do you start it? How is Jetty started by SBT? I think it is not possible to do hot code replacement with Eclipse out of the box when your SBT build forks a new process to run the Jetty.

Comment: I had the same issue with my Gradle build. It was starting a Tomcat via a plugin but i couldn't debug the web application because the Tomcat was not started in the Gradle build process. I came up with the solution to start the Tomcat directly (embedded) in the Gradle build. This allowed me to debug via Eclipse, and to change code while debugging. The Gradle build was started by an Eclipse Java launch configration. As far as I know, Eclipse needs the source files being run in the source folders of the project.

Comment: Consider using remote debugging feature if it doesn't work directly.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich SBT works like Maven. You usually start it from a shell and execute some specific task (like compile or jetty:start). I'll try out to execute it from inside Eclipse.